# Retrieve File Names from a folder while new files are being created by other application

Tags: c#, .net, linq, filesystems

I have a task to process files from a folder using C#,  the naming convention of the files is like this:

```
0000001.log
0000002.log
....
00nnnnn.log
```

Given a parameter x, all the files with the name smaller than x will be processed.  After processing, the file will be deleted.

At the same time, another application will constantly adding log files to this folder, with an incremental number.

I know I can use `GetFiles` or `EnumerateFiles` & linq in C# to filter the files I need.

If I understand correctly, these two method will load all the file names into memory first, and then filter out the ones I need.

Since `nnnn` is quite a large number,  I think it will be more efficient if I have a way to retrieve only the file names I need, i.e. x number of files, without loading all file names

Is this possible?

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` does not retrieve all the matching file names into memory first. See remarks here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx, or if seeing is believing, follow the code for it at referencesource.microsoft.com, or attach ProcessMonitor to a test app and you will see it is retrieving the file names incrementally. **If** you exit the iteration early, you won't pay the whole cost.

Comment: @Kason, no, that won't work, as I need the file from 1 to x.

Comment: @steve16351, Yes I knew EnumerateFiles can exit early, but it seems no guarantee it will sort by file name in ascending order.  Please don't forget, the other application will keep adding file to the same folder.

Comment: quite a large number? I really want to know how large the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file system watcher to receive a notification on a new file creation:

```
System.IO.FileSystemWatcher m_Watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher(); 
m_Watcher.Path = folderPath; 
m_Watcher.Filter = strFilter; 
m_Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | 
                     NotifyFilters.LastWrite | 
                     NotifyFilters.FileName | 
                     NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

m_Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
m_Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
```

While strFilter is the filter for the file names for example: "*.txt";

For further information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can make a for iterate and add an if condition into it.If the condition is true then looad that file.